# Python 2 to 3: telling 2to3 "I got this"

Tags: python-2to3

with either linters or `coverage.py`, you can tell the tool to ignore certain parts of your code.

for example, `#pragma: no cover` tells coverage not to count an exception branch as missing:

```
    except (Exception,) as e:    #pragma: no cover
        if cpdb(): pdb.set_trace()
        raise
```

Now, I know I can exclude specific fixers from `2to3`.  For example, to avoid fixing imports below, I can use `2to3 test_import_stringio.py -x imports`.

But can use code annotations/directives to keep the fixer active, except at certain locations?  For example, this bit of code is already adjusted to work for 2 **and** 3.

```
#this import should work fine in 2 AND 3.
try:
    from io import StringIO
except ImportError:
    #pragma-for-2to3:  skip
    from StringIO import StringIO
```

but `2to3` helpfully converts, because there is no such directive/pragma

And now this won't work in 2:

```
#this tests should work fine in 2 and 3.
try:
    from io import StringIO
except ImportError:
    #pragma-for-2to3:  skip
    from io import StringIO
```

Reason I am asking is because I want to avoid a big-bang approach.  I intend to refactor code bit by bit, starting with unittests, to run under 2 and 3.

I am guessing this is not possible, just looking at my options.  What I'll probably end up doing is to run the converter only on imports with `-f imports` for example, check what it ended up doing, do that manually myself on the code and then exclude imports from future consideration with `-x imports`.